# Is it possible to create red/blue 3d color in LaTeX?

Tags: beamer, 3d

Is it possible to create a red/blue 3d effect in LaTeX using a preexisting package? If not, would anybody have any insight into how to go about this?

I am planning to make a beamer presentation on 3d effects, and the ability to have a 3d(even if it is gimickey) would be fun.

Link on red/blue 3d http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D

Comment: the "red/blue effect" is identified by the linked article as what is traditionally known as a stereopticon or stereoscopic effect, as used to produce 3d movies where one must wear special glasses, with one lens red and the other blue, to get the effect.

Comment: not exactly what you're asking, but plain tex, and black/white, but possibly interesting: a tugboat article, "[stereographic pictures using TeX](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb15-4/tb45foss.pdf)".  the effect is good at close range, on paper; not sure how effective it might be on a beamer projection.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Nice reference!

Comment: For what kind of material do you want to produce a 3D effect? Normal text, pictures, diagrams (e.g. TikZ)? Whole Beamer frames?